# error while make the Makefile on cross compiler on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04, cross-compiling, qmake, yocto

i'm using qt5.5 on my computer.
And i got the issue while i make my Makefile.

I will got Makefile by sending this code.

```
qmake -spec ../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/devices/linux-imx6-g++/ -o Makefile test.pro
```

It has no problem with that but when send "make " to build my program, it will show this error to me.

```
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -mfloat-abi=softfp -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -I../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -I../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -I../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I. -I../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/devices/linux-imx6-g++ -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from ../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:37:0,
             from ../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h:37,
             from ../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:37,
             from ../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1,
             from mainwindow.h:4,
             from main.cpp:1:
../../sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:39:21: fatal error: cstddef: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

And in the other method, i could do this command to get the Makefile too.

```
qmake test.pro
```

In this case when i make my Makefile it doing fine.

But if i using -spec to direct to the qmake.config that i want then will get the error like above.

I don't know why will this happened.

I'm using the meta-toolchain-qt5 for my cross compiler.

Did i miss anything or it is the reason that gcc version is too old?

Please Help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never call `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++` directly when using a cross-compiler built by OpenEmbedded. Instead, you should call `$CXX`. The reason is that the built-in sysroot in the cross-compiler is poisoned (it points to a non-existing path). See for instance the explanation in [gcc reports sysroot is /not/exist](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-September/026456.html). This change was introduced in Yocto Project release 1.8, see [Default Sysroot Poisoning](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#migration-1.8-default-sysroot-poisoning).

Comment: But i didn't call it directly it will search by itself.

When i using qmake then it will find it.

Comment: Is that my qmake.config might write in the wrong way?

Comment: This is my qmake.config.

`include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL         += -lEGL
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2  += -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENVG      += -lOpenVG -lEGL -lGAL

IMX6_CFLAGS             = -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1
QMAKE_CFLAGS           += $$IMX6_CFLAGS
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS         += $$IMX6_CFLAGS

#DISTRO_OPTS += hard-float
DISTRO_OPTS += soft-float

# Preferred eglfs backend
EGLFS_DEVICE_INTEGRATION = eglfs_viv

include(../common/linux_arm_device_post.conf)

load(qt_config)
`

Comment: If i want to fix it, i have to fix my qmake.config?
Or what else can i do the cross compile?

Comment: Well I'd only run `qmake test.pro` after sourcing my SDK. There's no need to directly call `-spec xxx`, unless you have some very specific needs. Ensure that you have sourced the SDK, and that qmake comes from the SDK.

Comment: So i can just run `qmake test.pro` then i can run my application in the different OS system without recompiling?

Comment: No, you source your SDK's setup script, run `qmake test.pro`, and the make. The first step, sourcing is *important*.

Comment: Thank you i got it.